# Serilog ILogger.ForContext throwing NullReferenceException in XUnit Mock

Tags: mocking, xunit, signalr-hub, serilog, asp.net-core-signalr

I am having an issue when trying to unit test signalr components using Mock. Here is where the issue occurs

```
 _logger.LogInformation($"Registering a Station with id: {Id}" +
            $" with status: {Status}" +
            $"{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CommandId) ? $", with command: {CommandId}" : "")}", 
            LoggingConstants.Component.MessageHub,
            LoggingConstants.Class.Workstation, 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppointmentId) ? 
                AppointmentId : LoggingConstants.NoAppointmentId,
            LoggingConstants.NoConfirmationNumber);
```

LogInformation is defined as

```
logger.ForContext("Component", (object) component, false).ForContext("Class", (object) @class, 
false).ForContext("AppointmentId", (object) appointmentId, false).ForContext("ConfirmationNumber", 
(object) confirmationNumber, false).Information(message);
```

In the Xunit Unit test class, it is being used as

```
public Mock<ILogger> MockLogger { get; set; }
MockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
Workstation = new Workstation(MockLogger.Object);
```

When the unit test is run, once it hits that _logger.LogInformation() message, it throws a

```
"System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at LogInformation(ILogger logger, String message, String component, String class, String 
appointmentId, String confirmationNumber)"
```

To verify that it is being thrown because of the ForContext, this test was used

```
_logger.Information("a") -> Works
_logger.ForContext("a", "a").Information("a") -> Exception is thrown
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's expected... You are creating a mock of `ILogger` without setting up what `ForContext` should return, and then trying to use the return of `ForContext` which is obviously `null`.

[You have to call `Setup` on your mock to configure `ForContext` to return a valid `ILogger`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods).

e.g.

```
MockLogger.Setup(x => x.ForContext(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), false))
    .Returns(MockLogger.Object);
```

---

However, it looks you are not testing anything about logging and is just creating a mock of `ILogger` to satisfy the dependency of the class being tested. In that case, you don't have to create a mock at all... You can simply use `Logger.None` which is a `SilentLogger` that does nothing (it doesn't log nor throws errors).

e.g.

```
Workstation = new Workstation(Logger.None);
```

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding a MockLogger.Setup(d => d.ForContext(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), false)).Returns(MockLogger.Object) underneath my initialization of mock logger. Thank you for your help!